# Why approximating dSigma/dS with dSigma/dK changes the ATM volatility at twice the rate?

Tags: volatility, volatility-skew

I'm referring to the paper "Delta Hedging With a Smile", Sami Vahamaa (2004). It mentions:

> By approximating ∂σ/∂S with ∂σ/∂K, it is assumed that as S changes by
> one unit, there is a parallel shift of ∂σ/∂K units in the volatility
> smile. If the current smile is downward sloping, the approximation
> assumes that the volatility smile is shifted downwards as the price of
> the underlying stock increases, and thus, all fixed-strike
> volatilities decrease by the amount defined by the slope of the
> current smile and at-the-money volatility decreases twice as much.

Let's say I have 5 strikes with it's 5 implied volatilities, with ATM strike being 100:

[image]

My understanding is that while S = 100, the implied vol of 25.5 in K=99 means that the average volatility of all the paths until maturity that end with S=99 will be 25.5. Now, if S goes down to 99 according to the paper the whole curve would shift upwards by 0.5 volatility points leaving us with:

[image]

Now the average volatility of all the paths ending with S=99 is 26, half a vol point higher. Doesn't it mean that the implied volatility of K=99 when S=100 was trivial/wrong/useless?

**I guess what I am trying to understand is: if the skew is already there to account for how changes in S affects the ATM volatility, why are we shifting the whole curve upwards by an amount equal to the slope when S decreases?** That just seems to me as having a skew that provides no or wrong information.

Thanks

Comment: I think the author is referring to the fact that at-the-money forward slope of local volatility is roughly twice the at-the-money forward implied volatility's skew. Implied volatility (variance) is a weighted average of local volatilities (variance) along different paths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is he then mixing in the same sentence local implied volatilities with (non-local) implied volatility skew?

Comment: I think I misinterpreted. I think what he refers to is the fact that under local volatility, the ATMF IV changes at twice the rate of the current IV skew's slope. Since IV and LV curves crosses at the ATMF point, when spot moves from \$100 to \$90 and assuming a fixed LV surface, the original ATMF point (\$100) crosses LV curve at \$100 and new ATMF point (\$90) crosses at same LV curve at $90, so we see that ATMF IV changes from LV(\$100) to LV(\$90). Since LV has twice the slope of IV, hence ATMF IV changes at twice IV's slope.

Comment: As for the qs why we are shifting the whole IV curve. It is because IV curve represents fixed strike implied volatilities. If IV curve remains the same when spot moves, a $K strike option will have the same IV over its life. This regime is known as "Sticky Strike". Alternative regimes include "Sticky Delta" where IV as a function of moneyness is constant through time, and "Stick Local Volatility" or "Sticky Implied Tree" which is what I think the author is depicting.